# Rails 3.2.3 Routing Error (trying to add articles)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm new to rails 3 (and rails in general)...I built a site skeleton for a friends band and now he wants to add articles to his site...

So far all I had built were pages: (Home, Shows, Media, Contact) and header & footer partials... so nothing too fancy yet.

Heres what I did to add articles so far:

```
rails g scaffold article title:string body:text
rake db:migrate
```

but when I went to localhost:3000/articles I get this error message:

```
ActionController::RoutingError in Articles#new
no route matches {:action=>"home", :controller=>"articles"}
```

it says the error was raised in app/views/layouts/**_header.html.erb** on line #28 :

```
25:   <h1>Title</h1>  
26: <ul id="nav">
27: <ul>
28:         <li><%= link_to image_tag("home.jpg",:class=> 'hoverImages'), :action => 'home' %></li>
29:         <li><%= link_to image_tag("shows.jpg", :class=> 'hoverImages'), :action => 'shows' %></li>
30:         <li><%= link_to image_tag("media.jpg", :class=> 'hoverImages'), :action => 'media' %></li>
31:         <li><%= link_to image_tag("contact.jpg", :class=> 'hoverImages'), :action => 'contact' %></li>
```

here is my **routes.rb**

```
CsmlSite::Application.routes.draw do

resources :articles

match '/shows', :to => 'pages#shows'
match '/media', :to => 'pages#media'
match '/contact', :to => 'pages#contact'
match '/articles', :to => 'articles#index'
root :to => "pages#home"

end
```

why can't i view localhost:3000/articles ?
any helpful hints would be MUCH obliged!

EDIT: here is the output of my **rake route** task

```
root        /(.:format)                  {:controller=>"pages", :action=> "home"}
articles GET    /articles(.:format)          {:action=>"index", :controller=>"articles"}
POST   /articles(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"articles"}
new_article GET    /articles/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>" articles"}
edit_article GET    /articles/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"articles"}
article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"show", :controller=>"articles"}
PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"articles"}
DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"articles"}
shows        /shows(.:format)             {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"shows"}
media        /media(.:format)             {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"media"}
contact        /contact(.:format)           {:controller=>"pages", :action=>"contact"}
contacts POST   /contacts(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"contact_us/contacts"}
new_contact GET    /contacts/new(.:format)      {:action=>"new", :controller=>"contact_us/contacts"}
contact_us        /contact_us(.:format)        {:action=>"new", :controller=>"contact_us/contacts"}`
```

Comment: What happens when you remove `resources :articles` from *routes.rb*? - I'd also suggest giving a name to your routes, and use route_name_path in the `link_to`, instead of the action's name.

Comment: i tried removing `resources :articles` from _routes.rb_ ... now i'm getting this error... `No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"articles"}` on _views/articles/index.html.erb_ . any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm... figured it out. My routes were getting conflicted with a gems that I had installed... specifically `gem 'contact_us', '~> 0.2.0'`.

Once I removed that gem I was able to use `shows_pages_path` et. all

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite your view using paths instead of :action:

```
<h1>Title</h1>  
<ul id="nav">
  <li><%= link_to image_tag("home.jpg",:class=> 'hoverImages'), root_path %></li>
  <li><%= link_to image_tag("shows.jpg", :class=> 'hoverImages'), shows_path %></li>
  <li><%= link_to image_tag("media.jpg", :class=> 'hoverImages'), media_path %></li>
  <li><%= link_to image_tag("contact.jpg", :class=> 'hoverImages'), contact_path %></li>
</ul>
```

And one more thing in your routes:

```
CsmlSite::Application.routes.draw do

  root :to => "pages#home"

  resources :articles

  match '/shows', :to => 'pages#shows'
  match '/media', :to => 'pages#media'
  match '/contact', :to => 'pages#contact'

  # the route below is not necessary (it is generated by `resources :articles`)
  # match '/articles', :to => 'articles#index'
```

end

Comment: i went ahead and tried this.... but now im getting this error: `undefined local variable or method shows_pages_path for #<#<Class:0x000001029b74d8>:0x0000010299a680>` when i try and access localhost:3000/articles

Comment: @tim-gruns hm.. could you paste output of the `rake routes` task at the end of your question ?

Comment: yep...everything looks normal as far as I understand.